# BlankPage does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent()'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

As I understand it, this error is thrown when there is a mismatch between the files referenced. Still can't figure out the issue. Things are spelled correctly from what I can tell but it still isn't letting me initialize the list and it won't let me reference the 'listView' Listview. Would appreciate some help tremendously.

Should be the C# of the offending file. Notice the namespace and the method names. [image]

Should be the XAML of the offending file. Notice the X:Class name. It matches the Class Name from the corresponding c# page. [image]

Comment: your C# file should inherit from ContentPage, not Page

Comment: Error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Jason is right, inherit from `ContentPage`, if the error persists clean your solution and rebuild.